# Can you point me to recent developments in operating systems?

Tags: operating-system

It has been a full 19 years since I studied operating systems and need am looking for a list of recent developments. So any thing since Virtual Memory, paging, all of the good stuff.

I would prefer a book so I can get everything in one place. I'll pick up 'Understanding the Linux Kernel' from O'reilly to get started.

Comment: The rise of journaling file systems? The continuation of micro- vs. monolithic-kernels? Zero copy? Improved SMP? O(1) scheduling? In physics we'd call what you are looking for a "review paper". No idea where you find such a thing for operating systems. Attempting to supply a review in a SO thread is, however, counter indicated: it's a discussion and/or too long.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [language-based/managed operating systems](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Language-based_system) are somewhat recent and interesting, they rely on compiler/linker to enforce policies instead of runtime hardware-checks (so that, for example, all kernel code and user code run in the same process)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean developments or trends?  Much of what is seen today is just repackaging or re-labeling of old ideas.  Linux can trace its roots to a large multi-processor mainframe of the late 1960's.